why blob not working while in new Image src
 <input type="file" @change="handleUpdateFIle">

I'm having trouble running the following code snippet in my  application. When I try to set the src of an img element using the result of a FileReader object, I get an error saying "img src is not valid". Can you help me fix this issue?
const handleUpdateFIle = (e: file) => {
  const file= e.target.files[0]
  const reader = new FileReader()
  const img = new Image()
  reader.onload = () => {
      const arrayBuffer = reader.result
      const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer],{type: file.type || 'image/png'})
      console.log('blob',blob)
      const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      img.src = url
   //img.src blob:http:xxx
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
}

console tip
Uncaught (in promise) img src is not valid

I've tried using readAsDataURL instead of readAsArrayBuffer, but I still get the same error. Can you please provide a solution?
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications#example_using_object_urls_to_display_images

Will probably not solve your issue, but why do you go into a FileReader if you're just going to make a Blob out of the same data? Just us the File object directly.

Where is the rejected promise coming from? In your code img.src would escape any potential promise, so certainly this error message is from somewhere else.

Answered! Good luck! :)

Friend, you're using a FileReader to generate a blob when the file got from the <input> field is already blob like.
See if this example works for you:


const handleUpdateFile = fileEvent =>
{
  const file = fileEvent.target.files[0];
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  const out = document.querySelector('#myTest');
  
  img.addEventListener('load', loadEvent => URL.revokeObjectURL(loadEvent.target.src));
  img.src = url;
  
  console.clear();
  console.log('Generated URL:', url);
  
  out.replaceChildren(img);
}

// TEST \\
document
  .querySelector('#myFileSelector')
  .addEventListener('change', handleUpdateFile);
<div>
  <input id="myFileSelector" type="file" accept="image/*" />
</div>
<div id="myTest"></div>



NOTE that Object URLs are usable only at the environment that sets them (like the client used). This means the generated URL by URL.createObjectURL() is not accessible in other clients (because the generator client does not turn into a server to serve the link). In other words, if the URL is generated in Chrome, you can't retrieve the file at Firefox with that URL.

The reason it's not working is because the src* attribute accepts a URL, which is a String — but here you are inserting an array buffer**.
You have to either...

Convert it to a Data URL*** first.
Host it somewhere and then use that hosted URL.

Example 1: Using a Data URL
JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b4kdwr38/


const handleUpdateFile = (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) return;

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    const base64String = arrayBufferToBase64(arrayBuffer); // Convert ArrayBuffer to Base64
    const dataUrl = `data:${file.type || 'image/png'};base64,${base64String}`;
    console.log(dataUrl);
    
    // Options: Append it to the DOM or set an existing element's `src` to the Data URL.
    
    // Option 1: Assign to an existing element.
    document.getElementById("preview").src = dataUrl;

    // Option 2: Append it to the DOM.
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); // Read the file as ArrayBuffer
};

// Helper function to convert ArrayBuffer to Base64
const arrayBufferToBase64 = (buffer) => {
  let binary = '';
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  const len = bytes.byteLength;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return btoa(binary);
};
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#input {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

#preview {
  width: 480px;
  height: 270px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3ch;
  overflow: clip;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div id="container" onchange="handleUpdateFile(event)">
  <input id="input" type="file" />
  <img id="preview" />
</div>





Example 2: Hosting it:
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// Set up storage configuration with multer
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'uploads/', // Folder where files are saved
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)); // Unique filename
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// Serve the uploaded images statically
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));

// Endpoint to handle file upload
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file uploaded' });
  }
  const fileUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/uploads/${req.file.filename}`;
  res.json({ fileUrl });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

Then, on the front-end use the following:
<img src="http://localhost:3000/uploads/123456789.jpg" />

* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#src
** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer
*** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/URI/Schemes/data

What's the downvote for?

Because this answer is not useful: it's technically wrong, URL.createObjectURL() does return a string, not an ArrayBuffer; and then it promotes terrible ways to to consume a Blob, FileReader should be considered deprecated, if your script doesn't access the ArrayBuffer data you don't need it, and you almost never want a data: URL.

@Kaiido But it works. ‍♂️ I find your review to be somewhat opinionated. I'm not using createObjectUrl. Perhaps you should downvote the question, instead? Why is it bad to consume blobs? Why should FileReader be deprecated? It does access the array buffer. Why wouldn't I want a data URL?

OP is using createObjectURL, so the premise "The reason it's not working is because the src* attribute accepts a URL, which is a String — but here you are inserting an array buffer**." is wrong. FileReader is deprecated because the Blob interface offers better API to access the same features, e.g. to get an ArrayBuffer, use await blob.arrayBuffer(). You don't want a data: URL because it means the whole file has to be loaded entirely in memory, then a 35% version string has to be created on top of that, and then that has to be decoded again into something the consumer can use.

@Kaiido, I'm pretty sure the OP just wants their code to work. We're appeasing a new contributor, not the entire world. FileReader is not deprecated; it's going strong!  I don't see anything wrong with the rest of what you're saying. You have to load the image in through memory anyways. Why do you care what format it's in?

"OP just wants their code to work": And what makes you think that with this code it will work when their code should have worked (better). "FileReader is not deprecated; it's going strong!": Yes, at specs level we are numerous to consider FileReader is deprecated, even if there is no short-plan of actually marking it as such, it won't receive much new love. "Why do you care": Because here you're loading it thrice instead of just once!

@Kaiido There's a snippet embedded. Try it!
An issue filed on the w3c GitHub organization is hardly grounds for dismissal — and as for loading it three times, I don't see where performance is a problem here. It comes in as binary and it has to be converted to a URL, which means that it needs to go from a binary to ASCII. I don't see the problem. ‍♂️ I would implement this solution even if it loaded the image 10 times! What is it to the OP? Are they running an image server?

OP's code is also working, once again you didn't identify their issue correctly. When the one posting such a comment is Domenic Denicola, yes it means something. And yes loading a file in memory 3.35x is an issue. You're going to blow the memory for no good. No they don't need to go from binary to ASCII, a blob URL avoids that: its just a pointer to the data on disk, which thus doesn't need to be copied to memory until the consumer actually needs it (so e.g. if the file is a huge video, it doesn't have to hold everything).

And if you think you don't have enough information from OP to be able to answer their question, then do not answer, ask for clarifications/vote to close.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
